# How to add colors to emojis using reportlab python?

Tags: python, fonts, emoji, reportlab

I can´t add colors to the emojis using reportlab python, they look black and white

I have tried multiple things

1. I downloaded fonts that contains the emojis with colors but it did not work (https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji, and I used other fonts too)
2. I also checked on the internet, but I did not find anything
3. Obviously I asked chatGPT, Claude, Bard and anything too

Anyone has find the solution?
Regards

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.